# Nested futures in flutter to return list

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to return a List from a future and supply this list to a ListView.builder, but each post need to wait another future to get the data of the user who created the post. I tried first to return a future builder in the build method and inside it return a ListView.builder and for each Post I return a second future builder to get the user's data. It seems to be working first but the second future builder keep returning data when scrolling and the listview becomes unusable.

this is my code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: FirestoreService().posts(),
        builder: (context, posts) {
          if (posts.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && posts.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: posts.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (cobtext, index) {
                  return FutureBuilder(
                      future: FirestoreService()
                          .getUserById(posts.data[index].postedBy),
                      builder: (context, user) {
                        if (user.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
                            user.hasData) {
                          posts.data[index].user = user.data;
                          return postTile(
                            postObject: posts.data[index],
                            showUserInfo: true,
                          );
                        } else {
                          return Container();
                        }
                      });
                });
          } else {
            return Container();
          }
        });
}
```

Any idea how i can get a List out of the two futures and supply it directly to the listview build?

Comment: Wrap both futures in an `async` method and just call that.

Comment: The async method worked, but it compromises the performance of the app. Insted i loaded the posts first so the user has something on the screen and inside each post tile i get the user's data..

Comment: How would it compromise the performance of the app?

Comment: The posts page will keep on loading state for a long period of time with no posts displayed on the screen until all posts and each post user is loaded, while in the second method all posts are loaded and the user can scroll and interact with the posts even if the users data is still on loading

Comment: That has nothing to do with performance and everything to do with UX. And while it looks more responsive, you should be careful about user actions if they try to do something with user data in a post before it has been loaded.